# Umbraco server error after install

Tags: installation, umbraco, failed-installation

I downloaded umbraco and used the web platform installer. Everything went though okay and it installed SQL Express 2008 and a new directory under the default website in IIS. However when I launch the website I'm redirected a dead page as below.

What do I do next?

Thanks!!

---

http://localhost/install/default.aspx?redir=true&url=/test1/default.aspx

---

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /install/default.aspx

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umbraco must be installed as a root website, It cannot be installed as a sub directory or virtual directory under a website.

There are plans to support this in future although I'm not sure if a date has been given.

For more info see [this post](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/3121-Installing-Umbraco-4-on-a-virtual-directory) on [our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org)

Answer (score 0):

In the install wizard. 
When you are asked to type in new web application and web site name, just leave them empty.

See this install guide
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEeC4Bd-QZg

Answer (score 0):

I just made a fresh and plain installing with the follow requisites and solved this problem:

- Add and configured the website in IIS port 80
- Pointed physical path to wwwroot
- Configured the authentication
- Unziped the Umbraco files in the root of server (wwwroot)

This solved but I don't exactly why.